# How to make a redirection to checkout on a custom add to cart button in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

I'm using WooCommerce and added the following code to functions.php:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_url', 'custom_fix_for_individual_products', 10, 2 );

function custom_fix_for_individual_products( $add_to_cart_url, $product ){
    $add_to_cart_url = wc_get_checkout_url();
    return $add_to_cart_url;
}
```

What I would expect is that when a user adds a product to their basket: this code will redirect the user to the checkout page without actually adding the product to the basket. However, it still adds the product to the basket. What is wrong with this code?

*Background:* I'm using *[Uncaught Error: Call to a member function generate_cart_id() on null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66268491/uncaught-error-call-to-a-member-function-generate-cart-id-on-null/66269345#66269345)* answer code but it doesn't work correctly for the above line, which is why I'm now working with only that line. There's no error in the server logs.

Comment: The hook `woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_url` is triggered once the product has been added to cart… Also if there is no products in cart, you can't access checkout page.

Comment: Thanks @LoicTheAztec, but also if the product is already in the cart, it doesn't work. It just refreshes the page `https://example.com/?add-to-cart=99` and neither goes to the cart nor the checkout page. The "add to cart" button on `example.com/shop/`, which automatically is generated by woocommerce does work. But my custom button on the homepage doesn't.

Comment: Looking at the source codes, on the homepage the button is: `<a class="wp-block-button__link xxx" href="/?add-to-cart=815">Product</a>`. In the shop the "Add to basket" button now points to checkout since the product is already in the cart: `<a href="https://example.com/checkout/" data-quantity="1" class="button product_type_course add_to_cart_button ajax_add_to_cart" data-product_id="99" data-product_sku="" aria-label="Read more about &ldquo;xxx&rdquo;" rel="nofollow">Add to cart</a>`.

Comment: You should try to use as link `https://example.com/checkout/?add-to-cart=99` instead of `https://example.com/?add-to-cart=99` Th

Comment: Yes, with that it works, thanks! Will you add is as the answer?

Comment: Ok I have added as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comment, to get a redirection to checkout page for a custom add to cart button, you could change the link to something like `https://example.com/checkout/?add-to-cart=99` where **`99`** is the product Id that you want to add to cart.

So the code for your custom add to cart button link will be like *(where **`99`** is the product Id)*:

```
$product_id = 99;
$url        = wc_get_checkout_url() . '?add-to-cart=' . $product_id;
```

Comment: Don't know if this has changed since woocommerce 5.7.1  but when I tried it says: Please choose product options by visiting {the_product}. I guess it won't work if product is variable..

Comment: UPDATE: It works but you need to put the variant_id instead of product_id for variable products. e.g ?add-to-cart=variant_id&add-to-cart=variant_id etc